# req.isAuthenticated() is false, after successful login

Tags: typescript, express, graphql, express-session, passport-local

I have a simple login by nickname:

```
async login(
      _: any,
      args: UserFindArgs,
      { req, res }: Context
    ): Promise<User | null> {
      const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
        where: { nickname: args.nickname },
      });
      console.log(req.user);
      req.logIn(user, (err: any) => {
        if (err) {
          return null;
        }
      });
      console.log(req.user);
      return user;
    },
```

after login console returns user, which is fine: [console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SptOM.png)

but when I try to get that user in query:

```
    async me(
      _: any,
      args: UserFindArgs,
      { req, res }: Context
    ): Promise<String> {
      console.log(req.user); // req.isauthenticated() is also false
      return "req";
    },
```

it's returning undefined

index.ts:

```
(async () => {
  const app = express();

  passport.serializeUser(function (user: any, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
  });
  passport.deserializeUser(async function (id: number, done) {
    const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
      where: { id },
    });
    if (!user) {
      return done("cannot find user");
    }

    done(null, { id: user.id, username: user.nickname });
  });

  app.set("trust proxy", 1);
  app.use(
    session({
      name: "mnbmnbmbn",
      secret: "somesecret",
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: true,
      cookie: {
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
        sameSite: "lax",
        secure: false,
      },
    })
  );
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

  const httpServer = createServer(app);

  const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs, resolvers });

  const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    plugins: [
      ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer }),
      {
        serverWillStart: async () => ({
          //drainServer: async () => await serverCleanup.dispose(),
        }),
      },
      ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault({ embed: true }),
    ],
    context: ({ req, res }) => ({ req, res }),
  });

  await apolloServer.start();

  apolloServer.applyMiddleware({
    app,
    cors: {
      origin: "http://138.68.66.201:5000",
    },
  });

  httpServer.listen(port, () => console.log(`started, http://localhost:4000`));
})();
```

What's the problem?

Comment: What do you get when you  `console.log(req.user)`.

Comment: @Yilmaz undefined

Comment: Your context function needs to look at the cookie and see if an authenticated user is making the request. Remember that your GraphQL server is stateless.